# Where is Do ... Loop without a condition documented?

Tags: .net, vb.net, specifications

Apparently, one can create a `Do ... Loop`-Loop without a condition. The following code compiles with .NET 4.5 ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vPYBak)) as well as with Roslyn ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a01gRN)):

```
Public Sub Main()
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
        Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

However, the grammar on the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) only offers the following two options:

```
Do { While | Until } condition
    [ statements ]
    [ Continue Do ]
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit Do ]
    [ statements ]
Loop
-or-
Do
    [ statements ]
    [ Continue Do ]
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit Do ]
    [ statements ]
Loop { While | Until } condition
```

Is this a bug in the compiler, a bug in the documentation or did I just not look hard enough?

Comment: It even does compile with .NET 4.6

Comment: Looks like a documentation bug.  Someone should report it to MS.

Comment: @dbasnett - I've decided to be "someone" and reported it. Don't know if anyone else has also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -  Do you have a link for the bug report?  If so we can all vote it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt, consult the [language *specification*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15039), rather than the reference:

> **10.9.1 While...End While and Do...Loop Statements**
>
> A `While` or `Do` loop statement loops based on a Boolean expression. ... An expression
>   may be placed after the `Do` keyword or after the `Loop` keyword, but not
>   after both. ... *It
>   is also valid to specify no expression at all;*

(*My emphasis*)

The language reference tries to be more straightforward but may lose essential details. The language specification should match what the compiler implements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key sentence in the documentation is

> You can use either While or Until to specify condition, but not both.

So if you want to specify a condition you have to use either. Without a condition you do not have to specify anything.

Leaving off the condition is perfectly valid and will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score -3):

See the **Parts** section below in the documentation:

*condition* Optional. **Boolean** expression. If *condition* is **Nothing**, Visual Basic treats it as **False**.

Comment: Documentation: _"**While**: Required unless Until is used. [...] **Until**: 
Required unless While is used"_. OP is curios why a `Do ... Loop` without While OR Until is valid. The NBF is not `Do [{ While | Until } condition]`.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, What does mean "Optional" in documentation? May be, an error in "Required…" for While/Until, not in "Optional"?